# Regex to match first occurrence of a string is matching the last

Tags: java, regex

I have the following list

```
Acid
stuff
goo
nasty
Probable
Acid
more stuff
Probable
Acid 
fff
ggg
Probable
```

I want to match everything between Acid and Probable. However my regex matches only the last match (`Acid,fff,ggg,Probable`) not the first (`Acid,stuff, goo, nasty, Probable`)

The calling class:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {


       PDFManager pdfManager = new PDFManager();
       pdfManager.setFilePath("MyFile.pdf");
       String s=pdfManager.ToText();


       if(s.contains("Thresholds")){

              BravoaltDoc_ExtractionNonDays Sum = new BravoaltDoc_ExtractionNonDays(s);
              Sum.ExtractSumNew(s);


   public class BravoaltDoc_ExtractionNonDays {
    String doc;
}}

    ArrayList<String> Day_arr = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<List<String>> Day_table2d = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
    String [] seTab3Landmarks=null;

    public BravoaltDoc_ExtractionNonDays(String doc) {
        this.doc=doc;
    }

    public String ExtractSumNew(String doc) {
        Pattern Tab3Landmarks_pattern = Pattern.compile("Acid?(.*?)Probable",Pattern.DOTALL);
        Matcher matcherTab3Landmarks_pattern = Tab3Landmarks_pattern.matcher(doc);
        while (matcherTab3Landmarks_pattern.find()) {
            doc=matcherTab3Landmarks_pattern.group(1);
            seTab3Landmarks=matcherTab3Landmarks_pattern.group(1).split("\\n|\\r");
        }
        for (String n:seTab3Landmarks){
            System.out.println(n);
        }
return docSlim;

    }

}
```

Comment: How are you matching against the string? You only show the pattern.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your pattern (except that you're making the 'd' in `Acid` optional, for some reason), so the problem probably comes when you're trying to use it.  Show the code where you actually matched this compiled pattern.

Comment: [It works](https://regex101.com/r/vS0hG5/1). The question should be closed as  off-topic if you do not provide a non-working code with the description of what is wrong.

Comment: I have added the whole code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code correctly finds all the matches.  However, since each find re-assigns `seTab3Landmarks`, you only get the last match printed out at the end.

if you only want the first match, you should use an "if" block instead of a "while" block (which finds all matches).

Comment: Yes but the idea is not to find all the matches, just the first one so reassigning shouldnt really be an issue

Comment: @SebastianZeki - that doesn't make sense.  if you only want to find the first one, why do you loop through all the matches?  and yes, re-assigning is a problem because that means you end up with the _last_ one, not the _first_ one.

Comment: OK. So I tried converting the 'while' to an 'if' but I think it still iterates multiple times. An if I get rid of 'while{ } altogether I get an error. How do I go through and match only once

Comment: that still gives me the last match

Comment: My apologies. You were correct. Please post as an answer. To find the first match all I needed to do was match once. Good learning point

Answer (score 2):

## Description

This regex will do the following:

- Match the sub strings starting with `Acid` to `Probable`
- Requires `Acid` and `Probable` to be on their own line. If they are embedded in the middle of a string like `gooProbablegoo` these won't match

For this regex I used the Case Insenstive flag, and Dot matches new line Flag.

```
(?:\r|\n|\A)\s*Acid\s*?[\r\n].*?[\r\n]\s*Probable\s*?(?:\r|\n|\Z)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

## Example

**Sample Text**

Note: the difficult edge case in the third line.

```
Acid
stuff
gooProbablegoo
nasty
Probable
Acid
more stuff
Probable
Acid
fff
ggg
Probable
```

**Matches**

```
[0][0] = Acid
stuff
gooProbablegoo
nasty
Probable

[1][0] = 
Acid
more stuff
Probable

[2][0] = 
Acid
fff
ggg
Probable
```

## Explained

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \r                       '\r' (carriage return)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \n                       '\n' (newline)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \A                       the beginning of the string
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  Acid                     'Acid'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s*?                     whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                           more times (matching the least amount
                           possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  [\r\n]                   any character of: '\r' (carriage return),
                           '\n' (newline)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  .*?                      any character (0 or more times (matching
                           the least amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  [\r\n]                   any character of: '\r' (carriage return),
                           '\n' (newline)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  Probable                 'Probable'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s*?                     whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                           more times (matching the least amount
                           possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \r                       '\r' (carriage return)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \n                       '\n' (newline)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \Z                       before an optional \n, and the end of
                             the string
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of grouping
```

Comment: Great explanation but the ability to only match once with the Pattern.compile is my preferred answer

Comment: For the explanation I used the match all flag in the regular expression. Which instance of the substring are you interested in getting back?

Comment: Ok, if you're just looking for the first instance of the substring, then you'd use the regex without iterating through all the matches option. See [link to a live java example](https://ideone.com/zWAOsw) to see how it would look.

Comment: Cool. Thanks so much